# Using Bootstrap with Angular 9 to order elements on page

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I would like to ensure that if the size of the window of the browser is let's say smaller then 600 px, then I don't want to use bootstrap resizing, just add an scroll on the bottom of the page. How can I do this? I've tried with

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
}
```

in my css files but it's not working.
Or is there a way to ensure that user can't make window of the browser smaller then this 600 px?

Comment: Shouldn't that be max-width?

Comment: I've tried with max-width also still, nothing happens. Maybe the problem is I'm adding this to the css of only one screen of my web app? because I need this only on this one particular screen